# one valid linux group missing in /etc/group but can be found in getent group

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

One weird problem. I'm trying to add one user(say myuser) to a group (linuxadmins),  but get following error.

```
sudo usermod -a -G linuxadmins myuser
usermod: group 'linuxadmins' does not exist
```

Then I try to troubleshoot but found group is not found in group database file but can be returned by `getent` search. You can find the 1st line (**linuxadmins:x:1000:some_ids**) of it's return and the dump snippet of /etc/group. Anyone has any ideas on where does this group come from?

```
[my_sit@myhost /]$ getent group
linuxadmins:x:1000:some_ids
root:x:0:my_sit,other_sit
bin:x:1:bin,daemon
daemon:x:2:bin,daemon

[my_sit@myhost /]$ cat /etc/group
root:x:0:my_sit,other_sit
bin:x:1:bin,daemon
daemon:x:2:bin,daemon
```

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/group` is not the only source of group information.

1. All lookups first go through the *nscd* cache daemon. If nscd has cached a group that was subsequently removed, it'll still show up.
2. Then the modules configured in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` are used. The "files" module reads from /etc/group, but there may be others such as "ldap", "nis", "sss" (AD/LDAP), and so on.

You probably have this entry coming either from a network source or a caching module. Test the configured modules (from nsswitch.conf) one by one until you find the group:

```
getent -s files group linuxadmins
getent -s ... group linuxadmins
```